# Using window.open in Ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank') inside Ajax success.In chrome, new window is opened instead of new tab. But when I called window.open outside the Ajax, it opens new tab.Please anyone explain why its happening so.

Comment: my guess is that chrome treats any window.open as a pop-up unless it was called in code that was directly triggered by a click. Since the succes of the ajax request was triggered by the HTTP response, and not a click it treats it as a pop-up

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code or paste your code for more help

```
javascript:window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
```

Comment: It works when I make my ajax async=false, but if(async=true ie., by default) it opens in new window in chrome. May I know the reason behind it

Comment: this might not be a reason. I can't explain you without looking into code.